# How to adjust padding of a menu using javascript according to screen size?

Tags: javascript, html, css

HTML

```html
<html>

<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="engine1/style.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="engine1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript1.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style1.css" />

</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrap">

        <div class="sec1">
            <div class="logo">
                <img src="../images/logo.png" width="100%" height="150px">
            </div>
            <div class="heading">
                <h1 style="color:lawngreen;">CITY STORE
                    <br>KIRANA & GENERAL</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sec2">
            <div class="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li>HOME</li>
                    <li>ABOUT</li>
                    <li>CONTACT</li>
                    <li>GALLERY</li>
                    <li>SERVICES</li>
                </ul>

            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="slider">
            <!-- Start WOWSlider.com BODY section -->
            <!-- Start WOWSlider.com BODY section -->
            <div id="wowslider-container1">
                <div class="ws_images">
                    <ul>
                        <li><img src="data1/images/1.jpg" alt="" title="" id="wows1_0" />
                        </li>
                        <li><img src="data1/images/p2.jpg" alt="" title="" id="wows1_1" />
                        </li>
                        <li><img src="data1/images/p3.jpg" alt="" title="" id="wows1_2" />
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="http://wowslider.net"><img src="data1/images/p4.png" alt="bootstrap slider"
                                    title="" id="wows1_3" /></a></li>
                        <li><img src="data1/images/p5.jpg" alt="" title="" id="wows1_4" />
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="ws_bullets">
                    <div>
                        <a href="#" title=""><span><img src="data1/tooltips/1.jpg" alt="" />1</span></a>
                        <a href="#" title=""><span><img src="data1/tooltips/p2.jpg" alt="" />2</span></a>
                        <a href="#" title=""><span><img src="data1/tooltips/p3.jpg" alt="" />3</span></a>
                        <a href="#" title=""><span><img src="data1/tooltips/p4.png" alt="" />4</span></a>
                        <a href="#" title=""><span><img src="data1/tooltips/p5.jpg" alt="" />5</span></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ws_script" style="position:absolute;left:-99%"><a href="http://wowslider.net">wow slider</a>
                    by WOWSlider.com
                    v9.0</div>
                <div class="ws_shadow"></div>
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="engine1/wowslider.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="engine1/script.js"></script>
            <!-- End WOWSlider.com BODY section -->


        </div>
        <div class="pre-sec3-bar"></div>
        <div class="sec3">
            <div class="sec3-heading">
                <h1>WELCOME TO CITY STORE</h1>
                <h2>WHY
                    CHOOSE US ?</h1>
                </h2>
            </div>
            <div class="sec3-content">
                <div class="sec3-content-pic"><img src="../images/p6.png" width="100%" height="350px"></div>
                <div class="sec3-content-para">
                    <h3>CITY STORE GROCERIES.</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="sec4">

            <div class="sec4-para"><img src="../images/img2.png" width="100%" height="363px"></div>

            <div class="sec4-image"><img src="../images/shop.jpg" width="100%" height="360px"></div>

        </div>
        <div class="sec5">

            <div class="sec5-img"><img src="../images/shop3.jpg" width="100%" height="430px"></div>
            <div class="sec5-para">
                <h3>.</h3>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="sec6">
            <div class="sec6-header">
                <h3>OUR BRANDS</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="marquee">
                <marquee direction="left" scrolldelay="2"><img src="../images/b1.jpg" width="150px" height="150px">
                    <img src="../images/b2.jpg" width="150px" height="150px">
                    <img src="../images/b3.jpg" width="150px" height="150px">
                    <img src="../images/b4.jpg" width="150px" height="150px">
                    <img src="../images/b5.jpg" width="150px" height="150px">
                    <img src="../images/b6.jpg" width="150px" height="150px">
                    <img src="../images/c1.jpg" width="150px" height="150px">
                    <img src="../images/c2.jpg" width="150px" height="150px">
                    <img src="../images/c3.jpg" width="150px" height="150px">
                    <img src="../images/b4.jpg" width="150px" height="150px">

                </marquee>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="foot">
            <h4>(c)2020 SHOP RITE.All Rights Reserved.Powered
                by NashInfotech.</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

javascript1.js

```
 document.getElementByclassName("menu ul li").style.padding = "1.5vh 50px 
      1.5vh 50px";
```

CSS

```
.menu{
  width:100%;
  opacity:70%;
}
.menu ul{
  width:100%;
  display:inline;
}
.menu ul li{
  font-size: x-large;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  color:yellow;
  background-color:green;
  padding:1.5vh 86px;
}
```

I have done the coding so when the page opens it should show menu shrunk from 86px to 50px, but it is showing 86px right and left padding. The Javascript code is not reflecting.  My goal is to obtain a screen width constant and then changing the padding according to it using Javascript. But first as I'm new to Javascript I just wanted to test if my Javascript code is working or not and it's not reflecting.

Comment: Check the updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will not work, because you are mixing class name and tag name.

Please, use `document.querySelector` or `document.querySelectorAll` if you need to update all findings.

```js
document.querySelector('.menu ul li').style.padding = "1.5vh 50px 1.5vh 50px";
```

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('.menu ul li')].forEach(el=> el.style.padding = "1.5vh 50px 1.5vh 50px")
```

**UPDATE** Here is a working demo for the provided markup. Everything works perfectly. The issue is here:  `<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript1.js"></script>` You loads your JS before DOM. So when JS starts working, it can't find the expected DOM elements cause they are not yet loaded. **To fix the issue, move JS to the bottom of the file.**

```js
        [...document.querySelectorAll('.menu ul li')].forEach(el=> el.style.padding = "1.5vh 50px 1.5vh 50px");
```

```html
    <div class="wrap">

        <div class="sec1">
            <div class="logo">
                <img src="../images/logo.png" width="100%" height="150px">
            </div>
            <div class="heading">
                <h1 style="color:lawngreen;">CITY STORE
                    <br>KIRANA & GENERAL</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sec2">
            <div class="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li>HOME</li>
                    <li>ABOUT</li>
                    <li>CONTACT</li>
                    <li>GALLERY</li>
                    <li>SERVICES</li>
                </ul>

            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="slider">
            <!-- Start WOWSlider.com BODY section -->
            <!-- Start WOWSlider.com BODY section -->
            <div id="wowslider-container1">
                <div class="ws_images">
                    <ul>
                        <li><img src="data1/images/1.jpg" alt="" title="" id="wows1_0" />
                        </li>
                        <li><img src="data1/images/p2.jpg" alt="" title="" id="wows1_1" />
                        </li>
                        <li><img src="data1/images/p3.jpg" alt="" title="" id="wows1_2" />
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="http://wowslider.net"><img src="data1/images/p4.png" alt="bootstrap slider"
                                    title="" id="wows1_3" /></a></li>
                        <li><img src="data1/images/p5.jpg" alt="" title="" id="wows1_4" />
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="ws_bullets">
                    <div>
                        <a href="#" title=""><span><img src="data1/tooltips/1.jpg" alt="" />1</span></a>
                        <a href="#" title=""><span><img src="data1/tooltips/p2.jpg" alt="" />2</span></a>
                        <a href="#" title=""><span><img src="data1/tooltips/p3.jpg" alt="" />3</span></a>
                        <a href="#" title=""><span><img src="data1/tooltips/p4.png" alt="" />4</span></a>
                        <a href="#" title=""><span><img src="data1/tooltips/p5.jpg" alt="" />5</span></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ws_script" style="position:absolute;left:-99%"><a href="http://wowslider.net">wow slider</a>
                    by WOWSlider.com
                    v9.0</div>
                <div class="ws_shadow"></div>
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="engine1/wowslider.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="engine1/script.js"></script>
            <!-- End WOWSlider.com BODY section -->


        </div>
        <div class="pre-sec3-bar"></div>
        <div class="sec3">
            <div class="sec3-heading">
                <h1>WELCOME TO CITY STORE</h1>
                <h2>WHY
                    CHOOSE US ?</h1>
                </h2>
            </div>
            <div class="sec3-content">
                <div class="sec3-content-pic"><img src="../images/p6.png" width="100%" height="350px"></div>
                <div class="sec3-content-para">
                    <h3>CITY STORE GROCERIES.</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="sec4">

            <div class="sec4-para"><img src="../images/img2.png" width="100%" height="363px"></div>

            <div class="sec4-image"><img src="../images/shop.jpg" width="100%" height="360px"></div>

        </div>
        <div class="sec5">

            <div class="sec5-img"><img src="../images/shop3.jpg" width="100%" height="430px"></div>
            <div class="sec5-para">
                <h3>.</h3>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="sec6">
            <div class="sec6-header">
                <h3>OUR BRANDS</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="marquee">
                <marquee direction="left" scrolldelay="2"><img src="../images/b1.jpg" width="150px" height="150px">
                    <img src="../images/b2.jpg" width="150px" height="150px">
                    <img src="../images/b3.jpg" width="150px" height="150px">
                    <img src="../images/b4.jpg" width="150px" height="150px">
                    <img src="../images/b5.jpg" width="150px" height="150px">
                    <img src="../images/b6.jpg" width="150px" height="150px">
                    <img src="../images/c1.jpg" width="150px" height="150px">
                    <img src="../images/c2.jpg" width="150px" height="150px">
                    <img src="../images/c3.jpg" width="150px" height="150px">
                    <img src="../images/b4.jpg" width="150px" height="150px">

                </marquee>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="foot">
            <h4>(c)2020 SHOP RITE.All Rights Reserved.Powered
                by NashInfotech.</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I used queryselector but of no use.what cud be the solution.

Comment: This means only that selector is wrong. What is the output of the code: ```console.log(document.querySelector('.menu ul li'))```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
    at

Comment: This means that you don't have this selector at all. Try this one please: ```document.querySelector('menu ul li')```

Comment: nope.same error.Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
    at javascript1.js:3

Comment: Then you have an issue with markup. Check do you have the elements with these tags? Do you have something with ```.menu``` class?

Comment: yeah tags are all set,only this damn thing.

Comment: Could you update the post with HTML markup starting from the menu?

Answer (score 0):

Visit https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp.
Try with "document.querySelector('.menu ul li').style.padding = "1.5vh 50px 1.5vh 50px";"